# how to insert bulk data from one database to another data base same structure using java

Tags: java, sql-server

I have two SQL server running on two different location having same structure but different IP a = 100.0.0.1 and IP b = 192.0.0.1. I have a table a.table and b.table of same structure. Now i want to move all data that is in a. Table from 100.0.0.1 machine to b.table machine 192.0.0.1 .I want to transfer this data using java either connection or by hibernate. Currently i am doing this manually by running SQL query.

Comment: i think you will need to fetch all data from a.table and insert it into b.table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you can use

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test1 
{
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception 
{
try
{
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/old","user","pass");
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new","user","pass");

String sql = "INSERT INTO users("+ "name,"+ "active,"+ "login,"+ "password)"+ "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

Statement statement = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);  

PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement(sql);

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users"); 
while ( rs.next() )  
{  
String nm = rs.getString(2);
Boolean ac = rs.getBoolean(3);
String log = rs.getString(4);
String pass = rs.getString(5);
pstmt.setString(1, nm);       
pstmt.setBoolean(2, ac);
pstmt.setString(3, log);          
pstmt.setString(4, pass);   
pstmt.executeUpdate();
} 
con.close();
con1.close();
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
System.out.println("could not get JDBC connection: " +e); 
}
}
}
```

Comment: I'd be better not to set TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE and CONCUR_UPDATABLE on read. That may prevent setFetchSize() from working which could be an important performance gain. Also using pstmt.addBatch() could speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

Create a connection with something like this

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbProperties);
//then create a query 
String query = "select * from a.table";
Statement statement = connect.createStatement(query);
```

save result in resultset or somewhere else : `ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();` then create a second connection to your other database like above and call an insert for each result in your resultset. there might be much better methods to insert so much data. i hear about bulk operations but i don't know how they work